# Converting quint32 into string in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm reading the data from binary file using the code below. The value of `header` is 0xB1B1B1B1, but the below code gives me the output B1B1B1B1.

```
quint32 header;
in >> header;
QString myString;
myString.resize(sizeof(header));
myString = QString::number(header,16).toUpper();
qDebug() << myString;
```

Comment: Because even though you convert to base 16 it doesn't magically add "0x" to the start of the string.

Comment: And what output do you expect?

Comment: i want the same value 0xB1B1B1B1 exactly . is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only thing you're lacking in the output is the `0x` prefix, you can just add it manually:

```
myString = "0x" + QString::number(header,16).toUpper();
```

Note that using `0x` as a prefix is a syntactic construct in C++ (and many other programming languages), but is in no way related to hexadecimal numbers themselves.